# $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ is uncountable. Can we choose a sequence from $\Gamma$ of which the sum is $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> If $\Gamma$ is a set of uncountably many different positive real numbers, can we choose a sequence of pairwise different positive numbers from $\Gamma$, say $\{a_n\}$, such that $\sum a_n = \infty$ ?

I am considering such problem and I think the answer should be **yes**. But what's the rigorous way to prove it? Please give me some hints and I will appreciate any help :-)

Comment: Maybe the answer isn't yes. We have that $(0, \epsilon) \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $\epsilon \ll 1$ is uncountable, but it is hard to see how such a sequence can be generated from this set. Granted if the pairwise disjoint condition was dropped then we could just repeated sum $\epsilon$ and get $\infty$ eventually, but with this I am not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If not, then there are only finitely many elements in $[\epsilon,\infty)$, for any $\epsilon>0$, and $\Gamma = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\Gamma\cap[1/n,\infty)\right)$ is the countable union of finite sets.

Comment: Ah..Cool answer!

Answer (score 5):

Consider the set $A_n\{x\in\Gamma : x>0, {1\over n+1}\le x<{1\over n}\}$ either these sets are finite or they aren't. If they are, then there are countably many elements $x\in\Gamma,\; 0<x<1$ since the countable union of finite sets is countable and we can form the sum:

$$\sum_{x\in\Gamma,\; 0<x<1} x$$

if the sum diverges: great, we're done, if not

$$\sum_{x\in\Gamma,\; 0<x<1} x <\infty=\sum_{n}\sum_{x\in A_n} x$$

However, there are uncountably many $x\in\Gamma$ such that $x>1$ so that we can find a divergent series by taking *any* countable subcollection of that.

This has as a nice corollary:  even if you *try* to define summation for uncountable sets, you're assured that they would all diverge anyways.

Comment: I suppose you could define $\sum_{x\in\Gamma} x = \sup_{S\subset \Gamma\text{ countable}} \sum_{x\in S} x$. But without a definition, the notation is meaningless for uncountable $\Gamma.$

Comment: Yes, but I'm only using it for the countable case, so I opted not to muddle that in there since the op might take that to be something he really needs to have in his own version, so it was a pedagogical choice.

Comment: But it is explicitly stated that $\Gamma$ is uncountable.

Comment: Not necessarily for the $0<x<1$ bit, which is the one treated. I could word it better, but I don't think it's fatally off given the structure of the argument.

Comment: Yeah, and your answer is substantially the same as mine, I just think, when solving problems about infinity, it is good to take some care to not abusing notation and terminology...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's a fair point, especially if they're learning about the subtleties of $\infty$. I've edited my answer to reflect a better structure for the argument, and added a fun comment on the end as something for the op to chew on. Thanks for your feedback!